# Credit card deposit to accout

Tags: buy-bitcoins

How do I deposit money to a bitcoin account from a credit card?  I just need to pay an acquaintance something I owe him and he wants it added to his bitcoin account

Answer (score 1):

You will need to **buy** bitcoin, then send that to your acquaintance. Other option is to convince your acquaintance to accept another payment method.

Most bitcoin sellers will not accept credit card because it is very easy to lose money from chargebacks.